# Chai PUT JSON Array

Tags: javascript, json, mocha.js, chai

I would like to make a put request to a report resource by using chai.request. In general the ressource asks for an Array, here a simplified form which your PUT request should looks like(Problem is the Array [...])

```
[
  {
    "type": "report",
    "operator": "string",

  }
]
```

The problem is that it seems I can not make a PUT request with chai by sending a JSON-Array to the ressource. I have the equivalent .json file

```
    "reportOne": [
  {
    "type": "MainReport",
    "operator": "Plus",
  }
]
```

But when I am sending this array to the ressource it tells me always an exception with "Format exception".

The strange thing about this case is that when I send the same array by "Swagger" manually there is no problem!

It seems that I just can not send it by using chai.request. I tried several things but without success. Also change content-type or create the array manually did not solve the problem.

Here is the whole request:

```
 try {
            response = await chai.request(Address)
                .put(apiPath + '/report/')
                .set('Authorization', accessToken)
                .set('content-type', 'application/json')
                .set('accept', 'application/json')
                .send(reportOne);  
        } catch (error) {
            response = error.response;
            handleError('Error: ', response);
        }
```

Comment: `"reportOne": [...]` is not valid JSON; it's missing the `{ ... }` to make it an object, ie `{"reportOne": [...]}`

Comment: Hello, Thanks. I have tried it but no success. I get the same error with:    `.send({
                        "reportOne": [{
                            "type": "Lookup",
                            "reference": "Unternehmen",
                            "operator": "mu"
                        }
                        ]
                    });`

Comment: Can you send any json content at all? Try `"test"` or `{"test": "string"}` to see if it is accepting values at all.